# Attribute error from SoCo class MusicLibrary that documentation appears to say is not an error

Tags: python, sonos

I am doing initial exploration in the SoCo module which is a Python API for Sonos. Following the tutorial I do

```
>>> speakers = soco.discover()
>>> speaker = speakers.pop()
>>> speaker.player_name
'Portable'
>>> speaker.ip_address
'192.168.0.11'
>>> speaker.get_current_transport_info()['current_transport_state']
'STOPPED'
```

So far, so good. Now, still following [the documentation](http://docs.python-soco.com/en/latest/examples.html), I do

```
>>> speaker.music_library.list_library_shares()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MusicLibrary' object has no attribute 'list_library_shares'
```

and, sure enough, `dir(speaker.music_library)` confirms there is no such method.

But the [documentation for this class](http://docs.python-soco.com/en/latest/api/soco.music_library.html) says:

> **Listing and deleting music library shares**
>
> Music library shares are the local network drive shares connected to Sonos, which host the
>   audio content in the Sonos Music Library.
>
> To list the shares connected to Sonos, use the `list_library_shares()`
>   method as follows:
>
> `››› device.music_library.list_library_shares()`
>
> `['//share_host_01/music', '//share_host_02/music']`
>
> The result is a
>   list of network share locations.

Now either the documentation is badly out of step with the version I just downloaded (0.18.1; it says not), or I need another pair of eyes to point out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question also on the [SoCo Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-soco/wXa-ISW_EO8) and this is the answer I got:

> This function is not included in v0.18.1, but will be in the upcoming
>   v0.19 release. It's unintuitive but you need to look at the v0.18.1
>   documentation at:
>
> http://docs.python-soco.com/en/v0.18.1/api/soco.music_library.html
>
> ... not the 'latest' version of the documentation.

I forbear to remark on the wisdom of pointing readers of the Getting Started page in the wrong direction.